# android drawable invalid start tag

Tags: android, selector, drawable

I'm trying to set a tabhost selector, as i found an example demonstrating that i should create an xml file in drawable like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/hotel_selected"
      android:state_selected="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/hotel" />
</selector>
```

but when compiling, eclipse keep saying that it's  an invalid start tag in this file.

please help me solve this.

many thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found a solution, I created the xml file by using a simple text editor (notepad++) and saved it to `/res/drawable` and compiled, result: it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 7):

Ideal solution should be to put the XML file in

```
/res/xml
```

Comment: This was a solution for me with the <shape> xml file.

Comment: Solution worked perfectly for `<style>` xml file if for any reason you want it in that folder

Answer (score 2):

i have came across the same error  and than solved, i did mistake of adding the xml file under values folder so it was not able to recognise selector tag. i removed it from values folder and added inside the drawable folder and it worked without any error. this was in case of Xamarin.Android.

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on the directory you want to create the XML file, selecect Android xml file, and then edit that file. This solved my issue.

Answer (score -2):

Its seems that there is no any error.

There may be some problem. But you can do one thing, do **Project -> Clean** , it may resolve your issue.